# Unable to run command using Azure scale set extension for Windows

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I am using terraform to Launch some Azure Scale set for windows. I have wrote below code for updating the dynamic IP of the VM created by the terraform.

```
publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
settings = jsonencode({
    commandToExecute = "powershell.exe (((Get-Content -path C:\\Nomad\\agent\\agent.hcl -Raw) -replace '108.98.16.4','${data.azurerm_network_interface.main.private_ip_address}'| Set-Content -Path C:\\Nomad\\agent\\agent.hcl) | sc.exe start Nomad"
    })
```

But its throwing below error :

> Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a
>   failure when processing extension 'joinNomadNodes'. Error message:
>   \"Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a
>   non-zero exit code of: '255'. The command had an error output of:
>   ''Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n'\"\r\n\r\nMore
>   information on troubleshooting is available at
>   https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "

Now if i am running the command manually its running without any error:

```
powershell.exe (((Get-Content -path C:\\Nomad\\agent\\agent.hcl -Raw) -replace '108.98.16.4','178.98.16.5'| Set-Content -Path C:\\Nomad\\agent\\agent.hcl) | sc.exe start Nomad"
```

Comment: Are you sure the command is really right? I don't think it's exactly right.

Comment: Is it typo or the last ")" is missing?

Comment: @VictorSilva ... Ya its typo error ... But i have added "^"  to correct the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the escape char "^" just before the "|" .. Now its running fine.

publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
settings = jsonencode({
    commandToExecute = "powershell.exe (((Get-Content -path C:\Nomad\agent\agent.hcl -Raw) -replace '108.98.16.4','${data.azurerm_network_interface.main.private_ip_address}'^| Set-Content -Path C:\Nomad\agent\agent.hcl) ^| sc.exe start Nomad)"
    })